# WordPress slug without custom post type slug

Tags: php, wordpress, url-rewriting, custom-post-type, slug

I have register custom post type with following code:

```
register_post_type(
         array(
            'labels'            => // array of labels,
            'public'            => true,
            'publicly_queryable'=> true,
            'show_ui'           => false,
            'map_meta_cap'      => true,
            'show_in_menu'      => false, 
            'query_var'         => true,
            'rewrite'           => array( 'slug' => 'movie' ),
            'capability_type'   => 'post',
            'has_archive'       => false,
            'exclude_from_search' => true,
            'supports'          => array('title'),
        )
);
```

The issue is that, the URL become for this post like:

```
http://yourdomain.com/movie/post_slug/
```

But, I need like:

```
http://yourdomain.com/post_slug/
```

Is there any way to remove post type slug "movie" from URL, like posts and pages display at front-end by default?

Thanks

Comment: I have already tried different parameter at `'rewrite'  => array( 'slug' => 'movie' )` like: replace 'movie' by false, Null, empty string etc. and it's not works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not think there is straight forward solution this. If you need this so badly you can use [Custom Rewrite For Post Slug](http://kellenmace.com/remove-custom-post-type-slug-from-permalinks/)

Comment: I like if there is a straight way, because I think it can be conflict with posts or pages slug.

Comment: I have search too much, but I think this only way to do it, thanks.

Comment: This does not work always, If you have attachments with the same name it will give it higher prio then this solution

Answer (score 3):

You must register your post type movie in init.

```
register_post_type('movie', $args);
```

To replace the movie from post link use the below code.

```
function remove_my_post_type($post_link, $post, $leavename) {

    if ($post->post_type != 'movie' || $post->post_status != 'publish') {
        return $post_link;
    }

    $post_link = str_replace('/' . $post->post_type . '/', '/', $post_link);
    return $post_link;
}

add_filter('post_type_link', 'remove_my_post_type', 10, 3);
```

After that you can set your post type shold be like a default post or page.

```
function set_my_post($query) {

    if(isset($query->query['post_type'])){
        return;
    }

    if (!empty($query->query['name'])) {
        $query->set('post_type', array('post', 'movie', 'page'));
    }
}

add_action('pre_get_posts', 'set_my_post');
```

Comment: I have already tried it, it works also but issue is, this is not right way. because the slug of post type "Movie" conflict with "pages" and "posts" slugs.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried:

> `'with_front' => bool` Should the permalink structure be prepended with
>   the front base. (example: if your permalink structure is /blog/, then
>   your links will be: false->/news/, true->/blog/news/). Defaults to
>   true

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type

Comment: I have tried `'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'movie', 'with_front' => false )`. but same result not works, it automatically add 'movie' slug in front. I have also go to settings->permalinks and save changes.

Answer (score -3):

It's simple: set `'rewrite'-> true` in your `args array`.