# Custom post type: remove slug from posts containing /newses/ but keep page with slug /newses

Tags: php, wordpress, url, url-rewriting, custom-post-type

I want to remove slug 'newses' from custom post type, for example:

`example.com/lorem-ipsum` instead of `example.com/newses/lorem-ipsum`

but I also have page `example.com/newses` which doesn't work when I use [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39655213/wordpress-slug-without-custom-post-type-slug)

Is it possible to do?

With this code newses/lorem-ipsum and other posts doesn't work.

```
 register_post_type('newses', array(
  'labels' => array(
  'name' => __('Newses'),
  'singular_name' => __('News'),
  'meta_value' => "0"
  ),
'public' => true,
'publicly_queryable' => true,
'exclude_from_search' => false,
'show_ui' => true,
'query_var' => true,
'capability_type' => 'post',
'hierarchical' => false,
'has_archive' => true,
'with_front' => false,
'supports' => array('title', 'editor', 'thumbnail')
));

function remove_my_post_type($post_link, $post, $leavename) {
  if ($post->post_type != 'newses' || $post->post_status !=  'publish') {
    return $post_link;
  }
  $post_link = str_replace('/' . $post->post_type . '/', '/',    $post_link);
  return $post_link;
  }
add_filter('post_type_link', 'remove_my_post_type', 10, 3);


function set_my_post($query) {
  if(isset($query->query['post_type'])){
    return;
  }
  if (!empty($query->query['name'])) {
    $query->set('post_type', array('post', 'newses', 'page'));
  }
 }
 add_action('pre_get_posts', 'set_my_post');
```

Comment: Wordpress need this prefix to know what post type he need to query. You can use [those functions](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/203951/remove-slug-from-custom-post-type-post-urls) to remove the prefix, but you may have conflicts with pages sharing the same permalink then. To make it work with the CPT archive you need to keep the "newses" slug in your CPT definition.

Comment: http://kellenmace.com/remove-custom-post-type-slug-from-permalinks/ check this link

Comment: Please detail the method you use in your post instead of providing a link.